# Catching errors from spawned Node.js process

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is an example where child process `error` is not fired:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const childProcess = spawn('tar', ['--wrong-option'], { stdio: 'inherit' });

childProcess.on('error', err => {
    console.error('err: ', err);
});
```

Why is it so? How can the error (error code in particular) be caught from spawned process?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`error`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_error) events are only generated when spawning the child itself is causing a problem; for instance, when the executable doesn't exist.

To catch errors "thrown" by the child process, you should listen for [`exit`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_exit) events and check the `code` and `signal` arguments:

```
childProcess.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
  if (code) {
    console.error('Child exited with code', code)
  } else if (signal) {
    console.error('Child was killed with signal', signal);
  } else {
    console.log('Child exited okay');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Additionally if you want to see the error message:

```
if (childProcess.stderr !== null) {
  childProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```